# How to get the model object of a pushpin through a click on the pushpin in bing map?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing, pushpin

My pushpins are added to the map in a common way like this:

C#:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<PushpinModel> _pushpins = new observableCollection<PushpinModel>();

public ObservableCollection<PushpinModel> Pushpins
{
    get{return _pushpins;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
    <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:Pushpin Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle}" 
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                        Location="{Binding Location}" 
                        Content="{Binding Num}">
            </my:Pushpin>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</my:MapItemsControl>
```

On clicking a pushpin i can get the Pushpin as sender and get Location information. 
But i would like to track down to it's `PushpinModel` object to get other informations associated with the `Pushpin`, like name, description, urls, etc. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `Tap` event, instead of `MouseLeftButtonUp`.

Secondly, the `sender` in the event handler, is the `Pushpin`, and it's `DataContext` property is your bound `PushpinModel`, so simply do:

```
var pushpinModel = (sender as Pushpin).DataContext as PushpinModel;
```